# how to make a div with transform: translate 3d stack up on top of a masked layer ( not working despite Z-index being higher)

Tags: html, css, z-index, transform

I am trying to  make a div with transformation(CSS) stack up on top; here is the markup, I need  only the green div to show up on top of blue div. Basically the blue is a masked layer and the green is a dialog that shows up on top of it.

I tried setting the `z-index`, which din't work. The blue always shows up on top of the green.

Also if I change the blue div to be the sibling of the the green div then it works, but I want to keep the mark up the same i.e the blue div is a sibling parent to green div

Any pointers?

Here is the js fiddle link...
http://jsfiddle.net/YRTxt/9/

CSS

```
#wrapper{
    width:100%;
}
#red, #green{
    height:200px;
    width:400px;
}
#red{
    background-color:red;
    position:absolute;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
}
#pink{
    background-color:pink;
    height:250px;
    width:150px;
    top: 50px;
    position:absolute;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0%,0px,0px);
    -webkit-perspective: 1000;
}
#green{
    background-color:green;
    position:absolute;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    top:100px;
    right: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 1111;
}
#blue{
    background-color: blue;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0.8;
    position: absolute;
    top:0px;
    right: 0px;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="red">
        <div id="pink">
            <div id = "green"/>
        </div>
    </div>   
</div>
<div id="blue">
</div>
```

Comment: this is teh jsfiddle with transforms...http://jsfiddle.net/XMYFK/

Comment: You mean like this ? http://jsfiddle.net/YRTxt/10/

Comment: @AndreaLigios  i can only change teh css styles of blue and green  i cannot change teh classs of other divs, sorry i should i mentioned that earlier

Comment: I've not changed the HTML, nor the other classes... only worked on blue and green, starting from your fiddle. I'm THE one confused now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For z-index to work you have to have a z-index for both elements. I updated the  http://jsfiddle.net/rTkyR/, where I only added the z-index to the CSS two the blue and the green divs.

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="red">
        <div id="pink">
            <div id = "green"/>
        </div>
    </div>   
</div>
<div id="blue">
</div>
```

CSS

```
#wrapper{
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
}
#red, #green{
    height:200px;
    width:400px;
}
#red{
    background-color:red;
    position:relative;
}
#pink{
    background-color:pink;
    height:250px;
    width:150px;
    top:50px;
    right:20px;
    position:absolute;
}
#green{
    background-color:green;
    position:absolute;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    top:0px;
    right: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 1;
}
#blue{
    background-color: blue;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0.8;
    position: absolute;
    top:0px;
    right: 0px;  
    z-index: 0;
}
```